# Getting the value of a register in ASM at specific address

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I'm still trying to learn how to use ASM with C++ and I ran into an issue. All I want to do is read the pointer of an integer in a program.

The code of the program which is writing to this integer is as follows:

```
00A3EB6C - mov [edi+0C],eax
```

Now, all I would like to do is to get the pointer `[edi+0C]` at that address. The reason I would like to do it this way is because I have not been able to find a reliable memory pointer any other way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm sorry if it's badly worded, it's difficult to explain.

EDIT: My final goal is to display the value of the integer at the pointer `[edi+0C]` at the address `00A3EB6C` in a label on my Windows Form.

I am using a DLL attached to an external application, just to clarify.

Comment: The pointer is the value of `edi` plus `0xC`. I'm not sure what else you need.

Comment: I realize that, but how do I return it in the form of a usual pointer, like 0x00000000?

Comment: Or even better, how would I be able to write the value of [edi+0C] at the address 00A3EB6C to another value in C++? I'm still pretty new to this.

Comment: Are you using MSVC, GCC, ... ?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio C++.

Comment: What I really want to do is display the value of the integer at [edi+0C] at the address 00A3EB6C on my Windows Form in a label. How would I do that?

Comment: Your integer is at `edi+0C` according to your question. I'm not sure where `00A3EB6C` came into this. Are you saying `edi` = `00A3EB60`? I'm totally lost. If `edi+0C` is your integer address, and you want to return it, is there something wrong with loading it into `eax` and returning?

Comment: Okay @WhozCraig, 00A3EB6C is the address where the function "mov [edi+0C],eax" is occurring in the program I am reading from.

Comment: Is that `00A3EB6C` in your code or something else, like a library?

Comment: It's in an external application. I am reading the memory of an application which I want to get the integer from.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to put it. When the process I'm reading from reaches the memory address `00A3EB60`, how do I get the value of the integer at `[edi+0C]`?

Comment: Look into [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/).

Comment: Okay @DCoder, how about this. Clearly `eax` is the value being written to `[edi+0C]`, so how would I be able to know what `eax` is at the time when it is writing to my pointer?

Comment: To do that, you need to know when this "writing to my pointer" happens and have a way to run your own code at that point. That is what Microsoft Detours is for, though there are alternatives doing the same thing. Please read up on Detours and Code Injection in general, this is a very broad topic.

Comment: Side Bar: The "Its in an external application" should be in the original post. Not something discovered 10 comments deep. Please do try to include critical info related to your question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

So presumably, you have some function like this:

```
void func(...)
{
    asm {
      ... 

      mov [edi+0xc], eax
      ... 
    }
}
```

Now, to get that value of eax out of the function, you would need to pass in a pointer

```
void func(..., int *ptr)
{
    asm {
       ... 

       mov [edi+oxc], eax
       mov [ptr], eax
       ... 
    }
 }
```

or you can use it as a return value:

```
int func(...)
{
   int ret;

   asm {
       ... 

       mov [edi+oxc], eax
       mov [ret], eax
       ... 
    }

   return ret;
}
```

There are possibly other options too, but those are the easiest.

If you actually want to get a pointer to edi, you'd be using a pointer to pointer as the argument [or a pointer as return value - so I'll just show you the pointer to pointer, as the return value follows exactly the same pattern as above]

```
void func(..., int **ptr)
{
    asm {
       ... 

     // Assumes eax isn't used elsewhere below! 
     // Otherwise, find another free register. 
       mov [edi+oxc], eax
       lea [edi+0xc], eax      // LEA = load effective address. 
       mov [ptr], eax
       ... 
    }
 }
```

Comment: The `mov [edi+0xC], eax` instruction lives in an external application, OP is reading that application's memory.

Comment: Well, then there's nothing that can be done without binary patching - sorry, I thought he was LEARNING assembler, not LEARNING how to hack - find some empty space and rearrange the code.

Comment: I really appreciate the response, but the issue is that I need to get the value of the integer at `[edi+0C]` when the external program I'm attached to reaches the address `00A3EB6C`.

Comment: This is way more complex than I thought it would be...

Comment: Ok, so write a debug module that stops at that address, fetches the register value for EDI and add 12. Simples - it's only a few dozen lines of code, I'd say. But your "need" sounds like you are more into hacking than programming.

Comment: Well, for general programming I use C#, and have been doing so for years. I am learning ASM for the purpose of hacking, I am sorry I didn't clarify that, I'm new to this website too...

The problem with doing that is that it would freeze up the program, I would need to update this integer several times a second.

Comment: So, don't take so long to sort out what you are doing. Yes, it would run slower, but not HUGELY so - maybe around 1/100th of a second per intercept, probably less. I didn't say you take an existing debugger and do it by hand, I said write your own application using te debugger interfaces. I'm pretty sure they are available in C# as well, and whilst slower, you'd mostly be doing system calls, which are the same anyways, so probably no more than 10-20% slower.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how to do this? I would love to do this in C#, but I don't know of any way of running ASM in C#, so that's why I'm resorting to C++.

Comment: It's not something I can do on my Linux machine (not in a way that is useful on a Windows system, and C# implies Windows). Have a look at these functions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms679303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look through those. Would there be a way of reading `eax` in C#? Or would I have to use ASM through C++?

Comment: Reading a registter is done by GetThreadContext: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms679362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
I would suggest that you study the whole set of functions - I'm not going to tell you every function you need to use.